# Modify RGB pixels by channel

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I've written some Python/Pillow code to produce a contact sheet showing different versions of an image where the channel intensity is adjusted by a graduating list of factors. In this case 3 for each colour channel.  Is it possible to write this without using the if/elif statement as it seems a bit clumsy.  I know you can use numpy arrays but I'd be interested to learn if there is a python+pillow approach...

```
file = "an image.jpg"
img = Image.open(file).convert('RGB')

image_list = []  # initialise image list
RGBindex = [0, 1, 2]  # used as iterators through the 3 channels (RGB)
factors = [0.1, 0.5, 0.9]  # list of factors to apply to channel pixels
factor_count = 3

# create a list of images, split by channel, from the original image
source_array = img.split()

# now iterate through the channels (RGB) and the factors to apply to each and create a list of 9 modified images
for chan in RGBindex:
    for x in factors:
        # The point function updates the pixel values by the factor x
        wip = source_array[chan].point(lambda i: i * x)  
        if chan == 0:  # Red
            workingimage = Image.merge("RGB", (wip, source_array[1], source_array[2]))  # merge back with the other two channels
        elif chan == 1:  # Green
            workingimage = Image.merge("RGB", (source_array[0], wip, source_array[2]))
        else:  # Blue
            workingimage = Image.merge("RGB", (source_array[0], source_array[1], wip))
        image_list.append(workingimage)  # and add to the list
```

Thanks
Kevin

Comment: I don't know what you exactly like to achieve. It seems to me that in essence your question is more how to manipulate arrays than to manipulate images, is that correct? If so, can you give a sample input and a desired sample output?